# Time interval between two objects passing an intersection points

Tags: kinematics, collision, angular-velocity

In linear motions, a collision occurs between two objects if
$$p_1 + t_1v_1 = p_2 + t_2v_2$$
where $p_1,p_2$ are two arbitrary position vectors and $t_1,t_2$ are the time durations by which objects will cross the collision point. By taking the cross product with the encounter velocity $U = v_1 - v_2$ on both side, we will get $(p_1-p_2) \times U = (t_1-t_2)(v_1\times v_2)$. Thus, it can be said that for any $\Delta t$, collision would happen if
$$\Delta t \leq \frac{d_{min}U}{\mid v_1 \times v_2 \mid }$$

Now, I want to find the minimum $\Delta t$ for non-linear motions. Assuming the trajectory equations ($f(x)$ is second degree polynomial) are given, **does it make sense to virtually linearize the motions and adopt the same approach?** That means the length of each trajectory arch is the same as linear trajectory to collision point ($vt = \int\sqrt{1+f'(x)} dx$).

**What is the best approach to find $\Delta t$ threshold so as to predict a collision in such a non-linear motion system?** And can it be modeled for motions with non-vectorized velocity and position where the position of objects and their intersection point is given along with the magnitude of velocities?

[image]

Comment: Isn't time common, and hence $t_1=t_2$ for a collision?  I mean they have to occupy the same space _at the same time_.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou - If objects are going to collide, yes, in that case $\Delta t$ will be equal to close to zero. The problem is investigating a general case wherein there is a threshold for $\Delta t$ based on which one can say objects will collide or not.

Comment: What happens when $v_1$ and $v_2$ are parallel but different. The denominator becomes zero. This kind of trick seems valid only for special cases.